# Proof involving prime squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone please advise on how to approach proving the below claim.

Given an integer $i$, there does not exist a prime $p$ such that $8i - 11 = p^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Look at the expression modulo $8$. What value does the left hand side take? What values do squares modulo $8$ take?

Comment: I see, so actually, a stronger claim is true, p does not even have to be a prime. Many thanks.

Comment: Correct - and the claim still holds if $11$ is replaced by, say, $10,13,14$ or $17$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6k\pm1$. Thus, $p^2+11$ will be a multiple of $4$, but not of $8$.